# Is the BFPTouch interchangable with the BLTouch for mriscoc firmware without custom changes to Marlin?

Tags: creality-ender-3, marlin, bltouch, mriscoc, crtouch

I have two Creality Ender 3 V2 printers with a version 4.2.2 board. One printer has the official CRTouch, and one is nearly original without a probe. I found a similar product, a DIY project called [BFPTouch](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2890290), and I have almost all the parts needed to make it.

[image: BFPTouch]

<sup>Model and photo source: [Thingiverse.com](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2890290/files)</sup>

I use the Marlin-based [mriscoc firmware](https://github.com/mriscoc/Ender3V2S1/releases) on both printers. Version [Ender3V2-422-MM-MPC-20231202.bin](https://github.com/mriscoc/Ender3V2S1/releases/download/20231202/Ender3V2-422-MM-MPC-20231202.bin), and on my printer with the CRTouch, I use the [Ender3V2-422-BLTUBL-MPC-20231202.bin](https://github.com/mriscoc/Ender3V2S1/releases/download/20231202/Ender3V2-422-BLTUBL-MPC-20231202.bin) version.

Is the BFPTouch interchangeable with the CRTouch, like the BLTouch and CRTouch are? Is the wiring to the board the same, and would it suffice to use the `BLTUBL` firmware version of mriscoc that I've mentioned without further altering Marlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not interchangeable without changing the configuration of the firmware. These sensors do not require you to set the `BLTOUCH` directive, so this must be in your configuration:

```
//#define BLTOUCH
```

For the CR Touch this directive is required.

```
#define BLTOUCH
```

I am building the [Tiny Touch](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4661556) an even smaller version of the BFPTouch, in fact it is a derivative! In the last link you find [instructions](https://www.reddit.com/r/ender3v2/comments/nxm865/guide_for_bfptouch_on_ender_3_v2/) to configure the probe, which redirects to the setup of the BFPTOUCH.

Comment: Looks indeed even better. Is the Tiny Touch interchangeable with BLTouch? I'm asking because I rather stick with the standard BTLUBL releases of the mriscoc firmware than to make custom configs if not needed.

Comment: No, the Tiny Touch is also not interchangeable with the BLTouch.